# Why do I need round Icon for my react native app?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I have created a rounded icon for my app with name ic_launcher.png. I read that I must have ic_launcher_round.png too.

Why do I need that as my icon is already rounded. Will removing that cause any problem ? Can I remove this line also from andrid_manifest.xml ?

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Comment: You can read about adaptive icons [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)

Answer (score 3):

After Android 8.0 (API level 26) you can use adaptive launcher icons.
To add an adaptive icon to an app using XML, begin by updating the android:icon attribute in your app manifest to specify a drawable resource. You can also define an icon drawable resource using the android:roundIcon attribute. You must only use the android:roundIcon attribute if you require a different icon asset for circular masks.

You can also define the background and foreground drawables as elements by enclosing them in  and  elements.

A simple way to generate a adaptive icons is in Android Studio.

```
Select App folder -> right click -> New -> Image Asset
```

Sample Image
[image]

Sample Icon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

Comment: if that's your answer . please set green check mark for help others:)

Comment: Why did I add a new image asset, but it deleted the 2 files `ic_launcher` and `ic_launcher_round`, only the `ic_launcher_foreground` file was gone. I added the new asset again, it has the other 2 files, but the ic_launcher_foreground file is deleted. At this time, I can't run the project anymore, it says error: `resource mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground not found`.  The best I can do is delete all the mipmap folders, then add new image asset again, there will be all 3 files. I've been looking for the cause all day but no one has talked about this. Seeing they generate all 3 files.